# What is the threat-model of a malicious browser-extension accessing the data of *another browser-extension* that is security-critical?

Tags: web-browser, chrome, firefox, browser-extensions

Modern password-managers are moving towards a "fully-in-the-browser" model (see: historical [RCE on LastPass](https://www.networkworld.com/article/3183675/stop-using-password-manager-browser-extensions.html), and now 1Password is also [moving towards 1Password X as "the future"](https://1password.community/discussion/116902/privacy-com-integration-for-chrome-and-firefox) and no longer adding new features to the non-browser-extension version of their products).

Several sources indicate that using *other* browser-extensions alongside your password-manager-extension is a security risk; i.e. [1Password X's own](https://support.1password.com/1password-x-security/#protect-yourself-when-using-1password-x):

> #### Protect yourself when using 1Password X
>
> - **Limit your use of other browser extensions.** A malicious or badly made browser extension could interfere with 1Password X or attempt to expose your data. If you need to use untrusted extensions, consider using a separate browser profile just for 1Password X.

What are the risks in using security-critical browser extensions (password-manager, etc) alongside unverified, beta, or possibly-malicious extensions? How can one mitigate those risks without avoiding using extensions entirely?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/188771/how-do-password-managers-implement-secure-browser-integration and https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/193534/arent-browser-extensions-a-critical-security-risk and https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/191807/how-do-modern-browsers-isolate-different-addons

Comment: Using untrusted extensions is going to be a security risk, no matter whether you use a password manager of any kind or not. Extensions can inject code on the frontend of every website, and that would enough for a lot of damage.

Comment: @reed Yes, of course; but there's a substantial difference between "someone malicious gaining access to Tree Style Tab could access my Reddit posts" and "someone malicious gaining access to Tree Style Tab could access my SSH credentials / 2FA keys / ProtonMail authentication".

Comment: @schroeder I'd argue that it's a different question — yes, obviously, extensions are a security-risk if you allow them blanket permissions to websites; and that's well- and widely-discussed. I'm *specifically* curious what a WebExtension can access *in another extension's localStorage*, not on a website. (=